# How to connect SPSS with Elasticsearch

Tags: database, elasticsearch, spss

My data is stored in Elasticsearch and I need a way to pull it and use SPSS with.

Is there any method for this? Maybe a connector layer of programming I need to do on SPSS?

Thanks in adv

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I see is to use Logstash to export your data from ES into a CSV file and then import that CSV into SPSS.

A sample Logstash config file to export your data would look like this:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
   query => '{"query":{"match_all":{}}'
   index => "my-index"
   scroll => "5m"
  }
}
filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "@version", "@timestamp" ]
  }
}
output {
  csv {
     fields => ["header1", "header2", "header3"]
     path => "my-index.csv"
  }
}
```